# Constructing a SOAP envelope using LINQ to XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have to construct an XML document which has a SOAP envelope like so:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

Thought that SOAP-ENV is also a XElement, so tried like this:

```
XNamespace soap = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
            XElement soapEnvelope = new XElement(soap + "SOAP-ENV:Envelope",
                                new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xmlns:SOAP-ENV", soap.NamespaceName),
                                new XElement("SOAP-ENV:Body"));
```

gives this error:

> The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a
>   name.

Any clues?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
XNamespace soap = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";

XElement element = new XElement(soap + "Envelope", 
    new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "SOAP-ENV", soap),
    new XElement(soap + "Body"));
```